# How to find offer for a customer in Sitecore CDP

Tags: cdp

I need to find if a `customer profile` is eligible for an existing offer or not, if not then only I will assign a new offer. How to do that, is there any `API` call or any property in `Sitecore CDP`, to identify an offer for a customer profile?

Answer (score 0):

I think this totally depends on how you structure your customer data and how efficiently you utilize the data extension. Based on the info available for guests you can create your decision model to return a reasonable offer to a customer. That's what CDP is all about i.e. strong customer data and using tools like decision models, connections, and experience/experiments to provide the next best offer for a customer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the quest profile with custom data extensions, use that data attribute in the decision model's Programmable API to output it based on some of your business conditions. The programmable output reference will be used in Decision Table as an input column condition to assign the offers.

Sample example:

```
if(guest.dataExtensions.length > 0){
  return guest.dataExtensions[0].values.yourdataattribute;
```